# Cookies value isn't set when running from different domain

Tags: javascript, php, cookies, session-cookies

I'm currently making a web game that connects to a php file on the server to get certain values (this is to hide some codes from end-users). The server will create Session and store values inside it. This also means it will store the Session Id inside the cookie.

The problem is, the value inside the cookie isn't set if I'm running on a different domain than the php file. For example:

This will work:

```
Javascript address: "http://www.example.com/js/main.js"
PHP address: "http://www.example.com/php/main.php"
```

This will work:

```
Javascript address: "http://example.com/js/main.js"
PHP address: "http://example.com/php/main.php"
```

This will not work:

```
Javascript address: "http://example.com/js/main.js"
PHP address: "http://www.example.com/php/main.php"
```

This will not work:

```
Javascript address: "http://www.example.com/js/main.js"
PHP address: "http://example.com/php/main.php"
```

I've already enable CORS, and the PHP file can return values successfully, it's just the session id isn't set if the domain are different (no 'www' actually get treated as different domain...). Right now I'm thinking of forcing the user to go to the intended url using JavaScript. Although this works, I feel this is more of a hack rather than a proper solution and looking for a cleaner/ proper fix.

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify the domain in the `Set-Cookie` header for example

```
Set-Cookie: name=value; domain=example.com
```

obviously this will only work for sub-domains of the same domain, you can't share cookies between completely different domains. More examples [here](http://www.phpied.com/www-vs-no-www-and-cookies/).

Comment: I did try using setcookie() in the php file. Something like "setcookie("PHPSESSID", session_id(), 60*60*24,'/', "example.com", false, false)", but unfortunately nothing changed.

Comment: Did you try adding a leading '.' to the domain? See the notes in the docs for setcookie: http://php.net/manual/en/function.setcookie.php

Comment: As in ".example.com"? Yep tried that too, didn't changed anything unfortunately..